# gSOAP: REST Client withouth gSOAP server

Tags: rest, gsoap

I have a RESTful service and I want to use gSOAP for my REST client. Is it possible to use gSOAP without having gSOAP on the server side, simply communicating with the RESTful service that is offered by the service?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You can use gSOAP for the client side only, for the server side only, or for both.

In my client (in C) I´m using the function "json_call(..., "Some-Service-URL", ...)" to give a JSON-structured http-content to a Java-service.

See [here](https://www.genivia.com/doc/xml-rpc-json/html/index.html) for more details.

Regards Daniel